# Planning to travel from US to Dominican for 4 days and return on ESTA visa

Tags: esta

I'm a French citizen visiting friends in USA for 11 days on ESTA visa. They booked a  4 day trip to Dominican Republic while I'm visiting. Can I leave US and reenter 4 days later on ESTA visa.

Comment: An ESTA is not a visa. ESTA is an online system that tells you in advance whether you're eligible to travel to the United States under the Visa Waiver Program (VWP)

Answer (score 5):

If you leave the US and travel to the Dominican Republic you will be readmitted under the same I94 admission that you received when you arrived. This will cause you no trouble as long as you plan to leave within 90 days of your original admission to the US. In other words the total of your time in the US and your time in the Dominican must be less than 90 days.